# bootstrap-progressbar jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, progress-bar

I am facing a little trouble with a jQuery plugin for bootstrap progress bars - 
http://minddust.github.io/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-2.3.2.html

I want to provide preview of the progress bar to the user based on the selected option. The problem I am facing is that the `.progressbar({...})` records first change in options only and not the changes after that. The values does not get changed on subsequent changes.

If I select the option `"percentage"` then the text over the bar is shown as `"40%"` and if I select `"amount"` then the text over the bar is shown as `"40/100"`.

So the problem here is that if I first select `"percentage"` option and then change to `"amount"` still on button click I see percentage being displayed and not amount.

What am I missing in jQuery code?

HTML -

```
<div id="demo-progress-bar" class="progress">
    <div class="bar" aria-valuetransitiongoal="40">
        <span style="margin:0 10px;"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<a id="progress-bars-preview" href="#">Click to Preview</a>

<select id="progress_bar-percent" name="progress_bar-percent">
    <option value="percentage">Percentage</option>
    <option value="amount">Amount</option>
</select>
```

jQuery -

```
$('#progress-bars-preview').click(function(){
    var percent = $('#progress_bar-percent').val();
    if(percent=="percentage"){
        percent = true;
    }else{
        percent = false;
    }
    $("#demo-progress-bar .bar").progressbar({
        display_text: "fill",
        done: function(current_percentage) {
            $("#demo-progress-bar .bar span").show("slow");
        },
        use_percentage: percent
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#progress-bars-preview').click(function(){
    var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 10 + 1) + 10);
    var element = $("#demo-progress-bar").html();
    $("#demo-progress-bar").html("").html(element);
    $("#demo-progress-bar .bar").attr('aria-valuetransitiongoal',randomValue);
    var percent = $('#progress_bar-percent').val();
    if(percent=="percentage"){
        percent = true;
    }else{
        percent = false;
    }
    $("#demo-progress-bar .bar").progressbar({
        display_text: "fill",
        done: function(current_percentage) {
            $("#demo-progress-bar .bar span").show("slow");
        },
        use_percentage: percent
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcp9A/3/

Comment: I do not see the "click to preview" in the js fiddle. Can you check your fiddle again

Comment: That means there is no other way then re-inserting html? This do work though, thanks!

Comment: @Gautam: I left it intentionally so that it can show the change in progressbar.

Comment: @Gautam I saw through the code of progressbar js. This seems the only way.